# AS3 NumericStepper Component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am creating an Actionscript 3 application in Flash CS4. I created a movie clip called dropDown with it exporting for Actionscript as dropDown. Inside this movie clip i dropped a numericStepper Component. I also have a basic movie clip of a box with text that says Add Dropdown exporting for Actionscript as DropDownBtn. Really basic.

the Add Dropdown button creates an instance of the movieclip via an event listener and callback function.

Once the instance is created I cant seem to access the value of the Numeric Stepper. MY code is as follows:

```
   //create the load dropdown button
    var newButton = new DropDownBtn();
    //position the button
    newButton.x = 20;
    newButton.y = 20;
    //and add it to the stage
    addChild(newButton);
    //add the event listener to the button
    newButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, addDropdown);

    function addDropdown(e:MouseEvent):void{

        //create and instance of the drop down
        var newDropDown = new dropDown();

        //move it over beside the add dropdown button
        newDropDown.x = newButton.width+40;
        newDropDown.y = 20;

        //add the instance of the newDropDown to the display stack
        addChild(newDropDown);

        //add the event listener to the dropdown
        newDropDown.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, useDropDownValue);
    }

    function useDropDownValue(e:Event):void{
        //this is where I need to utilize the value of the Numeric Stepper
        //I thought it would be accessed as follows but it doesn't seem to work
        //I added a trace to make sure this function is being executed and that works
        //when i comment out my attempt at using the Numeric Stepper Value
        trace("useDropDownValue Function Accessed");
        var dropDownValue = newDropdown.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.

I had to reference the instance name of the NumericStepper inside the movie clip. Like this.

```
var numericStepperValue = movieClip.NumericStepperInstance.value;
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
 var newDropDown = new dropDown();
```

scoped to inside the addDropdown function
You need to move it outside that function to make it have a global scope

```
 //create the load dropdown button
    var newButton = new DropDownBtn();
    //position the button
    newButton.x = 20;
    newButton.y = 20;
    //and add it to the stage
    addChild(newButton);
    //add the event listener to the button
    newButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, addDropdown);



// GLOBAL SCOPE HERE
//create and instance of the drop down
var newDropDown = new dropDown();
    function addDropdown(e:MouseEvent):void{


        //move it over beside the add dropdown button
        newDropDown.x = newButton.width+40;
        newDropDown.y = 20;

        //add the instance of the newDropDown to the display stack
        addChild(newDropDown);

        //add the event listener to the dropdown
        newDropDown.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, useDropDownValue);
    }

    function useDropDownValue(e:Event):void{
        //this is where I need to utilize the value of the Numeric Stepper
        //I thought it would be accessed as follows but it doesn't seem to work
        //I added a trace to make sure this function is being executed and that works
        //when i comment out my attempt at using the Numeric Stepper Value
        trace("useDropDownValue Function Accessed");
        var dropDownValue = newDropdown.value;
    }
```

Comment: It thought it might be a scope problem. The instance of the object now exists outside thanks. I have one more issue though. I cant seem to acquire the value of the NumericStepper that is inside the dropDown movie clip and instanced as newDropDown. I  tried newDropDown.value and it doesn't seem to work. any ideas?